# Looking for a function that removes all comments from a script

Tags: regex, powershell, comments

I'm wanting to clean up some scripts and one of the functions I'd like is one to remove all comments.
This would be strings that follow a `#`

And text between
`<# comment #>`

Suggestions?

Comment: Can `<# ... #>` span multiple lines?

Comment: @AidenChow Yes it can

Comment: You should use the [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast) for this, see also: https://powershell.one/powershell-internals/parsing-and-tokenization/abstract-syntax-tree

Comment: The linked duplicate has a more narrow focus in that it doesn't ask for removal of _block_ comments (`<# ... #>`), but among the answers there you should now find a robust solution that handles those too.